# Which branch of mathematics researches zero-sets on nonlinear (general functions) - generalization of algebraic geometry?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Algebraic geometry researches zero sets of systems of polynomial equations. But there are zero sets of more general functions. E.g. solution of optimization problems usual can be formulated as the zero set of f'(x)=0. One notable example es zero-set of very involved function that is derivative of neural network wrt its weigths and biases.

My question - which branch of mathematics researches zero-sets of such more general functions and are there good textbooks for this.

If there is no such research direction - then why not? It could have lot of applications.

GPT suggested that topology and differential geometry could be the fields which I am looking for, but maybe more concrete themes can be mentioned if this is the case indeed?

Comment: If by "function" you mean a continuous function then zero sets are precisely the closed subsets. The answer then is "general topology." If you do not make any assumptions at all then you are looking at arbitrary subsets and the answer is "set theory." In any case, you have to narrow down the class of functions to get something interesting.

Comment: OK, and are there subfields of mathematics that makes some assumptions and that narrows down the class of functions? Algebraic geometry is one such subfield. But is there another subfield for maybe some kind of special functions - there are many special functions that are representations of SO(n) and SU(n) and other groups. Maybe such subfields are quite interesting and rich enough? E.g. Vilenkin "Special Functions and the Theory of Group Representations". Just some patterns what can be done and then I can figure out what to do with my own functions (from neural networks).

Comment: What is your level of math education? Did you take a real analysis class? A general topology class? A set theory class?....

Comment: BS in theoretical physics and MS in computer science. No general topology, but I am grabbing this and that additionally (my current reading list includes New Spaces in Mathematics/Phyiscs 2 volume set and also magnum opus by Urs Schreiber and of course basic courses in AG, DG), so, you can mention pretty anything, I will be happy to learn.

Comment: Then my suggestion is to start with "Principles of mathematical analysis" by Rudin. You are really missing some foundational material.

Comment: I have this agenda. Consider some spaces/set of spaces and describe them by invariants from algebraic topology and then see what is happening with invariants under the neural transformation and under the backpropagation. The inference direction has already been considered in https://jmlr.org/papers/v21/20-345.html and now I am trying to figure out what could happen under backpropagation.

Comment: And backpropagation more or less means solving f'(weights, biases)=0 or some other nonlinear equations. That is why zero sets.